# Shrunken screen in CoCos2d Box2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

When creating a simple HelloWorld Box2d template from cocos2d 2.0, the splash screen shrinks to half its normal size (after the flash). Its then as if every sprite is smaller. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Retina display mode? (It's on by default)

Did you add high resolution images (with -hd suffix) to your project?

If not, you'll notice all sprites being 50% smaller on a Retina display device because cocos2d is displaying the SD images on a Retina resolution surface. Either add -hd images that are twice as high and wide, or disable Retina display mode (look in AppDelegate.m).